# How to search a MediaWiki-based wiki for pages that use the template "underconstruction" and are tagged with "abcd"?

Tags: mediawiki, wiki

I want to search through a wiki based on the MediaWiki software for a list of pages which use the template "underconstruction" and are tagged with "abcd".  How can this be done?

Comment: Are you looking for an API query, or a way to search the wiki from the MediaWiki interface?

Comment: What search functionality is available depends on what extensions are installed on the wiki. The list of pages using a template, and the list of pages in a category, are core features; intersections of those are not. Advanced search extensions like [CirrusSearch](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:CirrusSearch) do support them.

Answer (score 0):

#### Using the MediaWiki interface

Using the [AdvancedSearch](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:AdvancedSearch) extension, like on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/Special:Search), allows you to specify advanced search options.

#### Using the API

A query similar to this might work:

```
/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&prop=templates&list=categorymembers&tltemplates=underconstruction&cmtitle=Category%3AAbcd&cmprop=ids%7Ctitle
```

Comment: Thanks :), This was very helpful. Will check!!

Answer (score 0):

First you need to [install CirrusSearch](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:CirrusSearch) extension. This will optimize search capabilities, and make the search very fast.

After that, you can use the built-in keyword to optimize the search. For example, use these keywords:

1. `incategory:"THE-NAME-HERE"`
   Use it to search for all pages inside the category name.
2. `hastemplate:"THE-NAME-HERE"`
   Use it to search for all pages that contain specific template.

But if you need to get all pages that have specific category, **AND** specific template use this:

```
incategory:"underconstruction" hastemplate:"abcd"
```

For more search optimizations see [this link](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:CirrusSearch)